# Adobe CQ: Injecting services via @Reference returns null

Tags: service, reference, dependency-injection, adobe, aem

I'm trying to inject a service into the component via @Reference annotation in Adobe CQ5, but after deployment it always returns null to me instead of service instance.

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service(value = GoodbyeWorldService.class)  
public class GoodbyeWorldService {
    @Reference
    protected Scheduler scheduler;
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoodbyeWorldService.class);

    public void get() {
       LOGGER.info("Scheduler is " + this.scheduler);
   } 
}
```

The JSP:

```
<%@ include file="/apps/cqblueprints-example/components/global.jspx" %>    
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>    
<jsp:useBean id="goodbye" class="com.cqblueprints.example.services.GoodbyeWorldService" scope="page" />      
<% goodbye.get(); %>
```

In the log I get:

```
2014-04-02 12:24:09.999 INFO [com.cqblueprints.example.services.GoodbyeWorldService] Scheduler is null
```

I've tested other simple print methods from this bean. They are working like charm.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show us another code excerpt where you actually get the GoodbyeWorldService and call the get() method.

Comment: Tomek Rękawek, i've added to the question what u've requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved! I have just updated the version of maven-scr-plugin from 1.7.4 to 1.9.0 and it started to work! Now I am retrieving my instances via @Reference annotations and I see my service in "Services" and "Components" tabs in Felix OSGi Console. Thanks to all who replied here!

Answer (score 0):

In order to have `@Reference` fields injected by the OSGi, you can't treat your service as a Java bean. Use [`SlingScriptHelper`](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/api/scripting/SlingScriptHelper.html) available as the `sling` object in the JSP files to get the service in a proper way:

```
<% GoodbyeWorldService service = sling.getService(GoodbyeWorldService.class); %>
<%= service.get() %>
```

Full example:

```
<%@page session="false" import="your.package.GoodbyeWorldService"
%><%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0"
%><sling:defineObjects/><%
    GoodbyeWorldService service = sling.getService(GoodbyeWorldService.class);
%><%= service.get() %>
```

Comment: I think you are right! But unfortunately I cant check it right now, because "sling.getService(GoodbyeWorldService.class);" returns me null as a service, not the instance itself. I am thinking that this is happenning because my service is not present in OSGI Console in "Service" tab, but how can his happen? ".services" bundle is "Active" in OSGI Console, the methods from the service are calling properly, but there is no "GoodbyeWorldService" in "Service" tab. Earlier it was there, but now it is absent. There are no any errors in logs. Any ideas, Tomek? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user2620644 you can check the components tab in the console. if your service was properly declared it should be there, perhaps deactivated. try to activate it and you might find the problem.

Comment: @Tomek, no, it is not there. My service is not listed in "Components" tab. Any ideas? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: And if your GoodbyeWorldService is not active it might be a build problem, if building with the maven-scr-plugin you should check that the resulting bundle jar includes an xml file for your component, under OSGI-INF, that includes the correct scr:component definition. Or a bundle dependencies problem, which you should see in the error.log.

Comment: @BertrandDelacretaz, no, it does not include the xml. there are only 4 .jar files, that are in lib folder (OSGI-INF/lib/...4 jar files (libraries)) and that's it. There is only "lib" folder in OSGI-INF folder. My maven bundle pom.xml is executing scr goal: [INFO] --- maven-scr-plugin:1.7.4:scr (generate-scr-descriptor) @ cqblueprints-example-services --